# Get notified whenever a file is downloaded via chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, download, c++

I want to perform some action whenever a file is downloaded by chrome and chrome only(no IE no Edge and no Firefox). Now I know of two ways to do this:

1. Keep watching the downloads directory and whenever a new file added to it perform some action. The cons of this approach are - if someone copied a file to Downloads I will still be notified, no differentiation between other browsers, if a download is cancelled I can still get notified.
2. Watch the History DB of chrome located at - "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History" and look at the downloads table. Everything is amazing but the only issue is chrome locks this DB so I have to create a copy of this DB to read it but Chrome does not flush to this DB immediately post a download but takes 7-8 seconds and I cannot wait that long and 7-8 is also not an official number and may depend on machine to machine.

What should I do? I want to get notified immediately(or asap) chrome downloads a file. Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd likely either need to configure an event in Event Viewer [`eventvwr.msc`], then use that event as a trigger in Task Scheduler [`tashschd.msc`], or it would need to be scripted and the script would have to be set via Task Scheduler to run at boot and to monitor if it's not running & restart it if it's not.

Comment: @JW0914 I am sorry I don't understand your answer, what is the high level explanation of your solution. I can take care of implementation details later.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that the flag `chrome://flags/#enable-system-notifications`
is enabled. This flag is defined as
"Enable support for using the system notification toasts and notification center on platforms where these are available".

Otherwise, unless you wish to write your own Chrome extension, see
if the following extensions are useful:

- [Download Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-notifier/gdekiloeocnfnochnkldpkmllmfiaeke)
  gets a desktop notification when the download is finished
- [Download Notify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-notify/nieieojodgghoomakdkpkeipnncmbhdo)
  will alert with a sound once a download has completed
- [Free Download Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-download-manager/ahmpjcflkgiildlgicmcieglgoilbfdp?hl=en)
  will get your Chrome downloads to automatically transfer
  to the FDM desktop application from which you will receive
  download notifications.